# Make map() return a dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following function:

```
def heading_positions(self):
    return map(
            lambda h:
                {'{t}.{c}'.format(t=h.table_name,c=h.column_name) : h.position },
                self.heading_set.all()
            )
```

It gives me output like this:

```
[{'customer.customer_number': 0L}, {'customer.name': 2L}, ... ]
```

I would prefer just a single dictionary like this:

```
{'customer.customer_number': 0L, 'customer.name': 2L, ...
```

Is there a way to make `map` (or something similar) return just a single dictionary instead of an array of dictionaries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why use `map()` then?

```
dict(
    ('{t}.{c}'.format(t=h.table_name, c=h.column_name), h.position)
    for h in self.heading_set.all()
    )
```

should work.

Comment: Or `{'{t}.{c}'.format(...): h.position for h in self.heading_set.all()}` in more recent versions (those with dict comprehensions).

Comment: Dict comprehensions appear in 2.7/3.1.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. The basic problem is that you don't create a dictionary out of single-entry `dict`s, but out of a a sequence of length-two sequences `(key, value)`.

So, rather than create an independent single-entry `dict` with the function, create a tuple and then you can use the `dict()` constructor:

```
dict(map(lambda h: ('{t}.{c}'.format(t=h.table_name, c=h.column_name), h.position), 
         self.heading_set.all()))
```

Or directly use a generator or list comprehension inside the dict constructor:

```
dict(('{t}.{c}'.format(t=h.table_name, c=h.column_name), h.position) 
     for h in self.heading_set.all())
```

Or, on the latest versions (2.7, 3.1) a dictionary comprehension directly:

```
{'{t}.{c}'.format(t=h.table_name : c=h.column_name), h.position) 
     for h in self.heading_set.all()}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return dict(('{t}.{c}'.format(t=h.table_name, c=h.column_name), h.position)
            for h in self.heading_set.all())
```

Answer (score 2):

As other answers show, you can use `dict()` comprehensions.

But, as a curiosity perhaps, you can also use [reduce](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce)

**EDIT**: As the comment says, `dict()` is easier in this case. But, for theory's sake only, what I meant was that it's possible to solve using only functional building blocks (without python's magic dictionary comprehensions):

```
def union(d1,d2):
    result = {}
    result.update(d1)
    result.update(d2)
    return result
```

Then:

```
reduce(union, sequence_of_dictionaries, {})
```

Alternatively, less clean but more efficient, using an alternative version of dict.update that returns its first argument:

```
def update2(d1, d2):
    dict.update(d1, d2)
    return d1
```

Or even:

```
update2 = lambda d1,d2: (d1, d1.update(d2))[0]
```

Then:

```
reduce(update2, sequence_of_dictionaries, {})
```

Where in this case `sequence_of_dictionaries` would be:

```
[{'{t}.{c}'.format(t=h.table_name, c=h.column_name) : h.position}
 for h in self.heading_set.all()]
```

Comment: Never mind, dict() with a list comprehension is a quicker solution in this case. But theoretically speaking you want a fold over union and an empty dict, which was what I was aiming at...

Comment: If your answer is wrong, delete it or fix it. If it's correct, please include an example of how to do that.